# Varnish http cache tags storage

Tags: shopware6

I have set up Varnish as reverse proxy for Http cache, xkey module is used as well.

Is Redis still needed for the cache tags when I use Xkey Varnish module?

In other words, is

storefront - reverse_proxy - redis_url

still needed in storefront.yaml?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's no longer needed then. Also see the docs: [Using Varnish XKey module without Redis](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/reverse-http-cache#using-varnish-xkey-module-without-redis)